# Using jQuery to check if value is not null

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, label, jquery-events

I have been trying to implement a float label on a form I am building.

I'm using this technique here and it's nearly all working fine http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/implementing-the-float-label-form-pattern--webdesign-16407

This is the code which works well enough:

```
// Code for adding/removing classes here
$('div.js-form-element').find('input, textarea').on('keyup blur focus',
function(e) {
  // Cache our selectors
  var $this = $(this),
    $parent = $this.parent().parent();
  if (e.type == 'keyup') {
    // keyup code here  
    if ($this.val() == '') {
      $parent.addClass('js-hide-label');
    } else {
      $parent.removeClass('js-hide-label');
    }
  } else if (e.type == 'blur') {
    // blur code here
    if ($this.val() == '') {
      $parent.addClass('js-hide-label');
    } else {
      $parent.removeClass('js-hide-label').addClass(
        'js-unhighlight-label');
    }
  } else if (e.type == 'focus') {
    // focus code here
    if ($this.val() !== '') {
      $parent.removeClass('js-unhighlight-label');
    }
  }
});
```

One thing that I'm trying to do on top of this tutorial is add or remove a class depending on whether the field has content but not rely on keyup, blur or focus. The fields that this applies to can also be filled in by external means. I need something which can detect whether the value is not null and need 'change' event to listen for.

I've tried this, adding an on change function, but to no avail:

```
        // Code for adding/removing classes here
      $('div.js-form-element').find('input, textarea').on(
    'change keyup blur focus', function(e) {
      // Cache our selectors
      var $this = $(this),
        $parent = $this.parent().parent();
      // Add or remove classes
      if (e.type == 'change') {
        // change code here  
        if ($this.val() == '') {
          $parent.addClass('js-hide-label');
        } else {
          $parent.removeClass('js-hide-label');
        }
      } else if (e.type == 'keyup') {
        // keyup code here  
        if ($this.val() == '') {
          $parent.addClass('js-hide-label');
        } else {
          $parent.removeClass('js-hide-label');
        }
      } else if (e.type == 'blur') {
        // blur code here
        if ($this.val() == '') {
          $parent.addClass('js-hide-label');
        } else {
          $parent.removeClass('js-hide-label').addClass(
            'js-unhighlight-label');
        }
      } else if (e.type == 'focus') {
        // focus code here
        if ($this.val() !== '') {
          $parent.removeClass('js-unhighlight-label');
        }
      }
    });
```

All help gratefully received :)

Comment: have you tried `null` or `undefined`?

Comment: If you mean here:
`
        if ($this.val() == '**null**') {
          $parent.addClass('js-hide-label');
        } else {
          $parent.removeClass('js-hide-label');
        }
      }
`
Yes

Comment: yes I do mean that but you need to take the `null` out of the quotations like this `$this.val()==null`

Answer (score 1):

Change your codes into this:

```
        // Code for adding/removing classes here
  $('div.js-form-element').find('input, textarea').on(
'change keyup blur focus', function(e) {
  // Cache our selectors
  var $this = $(this),
    $parent = $this.parent().parent();
  // Add or remove classes
  if (e.type == 'change') {
    // change code here  
    if ($this.val() == null || $this.val() == undefined) {
      $parent.addClass('js-hide-label');
    } else {
      $parent.removeClass('js-hide-label');
    }
  } else if (e.type == 'keyup') {
    // keyup code here  
    if ($this.val() == null || $this.val() == undefined) {
      $parent.addClass('js-hide-label');
    } else {
      $parent.removeClass('js-hide-label');
    }
  } else if (e.type == 'blur') {
    // blur code here
    if ($this.val() == null || $this.val() == undefined) {
      $parent.addClass('js-hide-label');
    } else {
      $parent.removeClass('js-hide-label').addClass(
        'js-unhighlight-label');
    }
  } else if (e.type == 'focus') {
    // focus code here
    if ($this.val() != null || $this.val() == undefined) {
      $parent.removeClass('js-unhighlight-label');
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks but this does not work for fields populated by external means, in my case a postcode lookup button. It also doesn't remove the label when the field is left blank and focus removed.